# Max length for WKT name

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, georeferencing, well-known-text, limitations

Is there max length limitation on WKT name?

see the **bold** text below:

GEOGCS["**GCS_Wake_Eniwetok_1960**",
    DATUM["Wake_Eniwetok_1960",
        SPHEROID["Hough_1960",6378270,297]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","37229"]]

Can you please point me to link or official documentation for WKT specs limitations or length?

Comment: The original spec was/is at OGC. Version 2.0 is making its way through OGC and ISO. Currently, Esri's limit is 63 characters, I believe. It used to be 31.

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy, is there official documentation for current standard?

Comment: There's some in OGC 01-009, ["OpenGIS Coordinate Transformation Service Implementation Specification"](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=999) (PDF). I'm not turning up the original CRS WKT spec. I can find a draft of the new std, but that doesn't really help you. Drop me a line, mkennedy at esri dot com and I'll send you some unpublished Esri doc on it.

Answer (score -2):

As commented by @mkennedy:

> The original spec was/is at OGC. Version 2.0 is making its way through
>   OGC and ISO. Currently, Esri's limit is 63 characters, I believe. It
>   used to be 31.